# if env variable exists then exit out of script

Tags: bash, shell-script, exit

```
#!/bin/bash   
if  [[ -n "$MYVAR" ]]; then exit; fi
# otherwise the rest of the script continues...
```

I'm trying to exit out of a shell script if a certain ENV variable is 0. The script above does not seem to work (I've also tried using `return` instead of `exit`.

Can someone explain how this would be done, or what's wrong with the line above?

When I type that in my terminal (replacing exit with `echo "YES"` it works just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding testing whether a "variable is 0", one can use:

```
if [ "$MYVAR" -eq 0 ] ; then exit ; fi
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
if [[ $MYVAR -eq 0 ]] ; then exit ; fi
```

The expression `[[ -n "$MYVAR" ]]` tests for a non-empty string value of MYVAR.  The string "0" is non-empty: it has one character, the same as the string "1".

`exit` will cause the script to exit.  `return`, by contrast, is used in functions or sourced scripts when you want to quit the function or sourced script but continue with execution of the calling script.  Running `exit` in a function would cause both the function and its calling script to exit.

Comment: @d-_-b  `exit` should work.  Could you provide more context?

Answer (score 1):

```
[[ "$1" -eq 0 ]] && { echo "Parameter 1 is empty" ; exit 1; }
```